# In Powershell v3, "-online" won't open in web browser

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

For instance I am typing, "Get-Help Get-Help -online" and I get this error:

Get-Help : Launching a program to show online help failed. No program is associated to launch URI

I use Google Chrome as my default browser. There is no option under default programs to allow Chrome to open the extension. Under the settings for IE there is a .URL extension that is set to be the default but powershell is looking for .URI. Have you guys run in to this at all?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm also using chrome as my default browser and your command works for me.

Comment: what happens when you run Start-Process "http://microsoft.com"

Comment: I get: Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I get this error if I have launched PowerShell as an Administrator, but not if I start it normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PowerShell with other user, you should login into Windows (interactive mode) with that user, at least one time, previously.

Comment: "Almost one time"? Maybe you meant "At least one time"?